# How to create a heap dump inside a Java app?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to create a **Java** Heap Dump Analyzer project for educational purposes. I preferred capturing the dump file inside my app instead of taking dump file as an argument. But I don't know how to do it.

I thought of running `jmap -dump...` command with Runtime by giving PID but I'm not sure if it's the proper way. Can you help me with it?

Comment: check this [out](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/programmatically-dumping-heap-from-java-applications). Found it [this way](https://www.google.com/search?q=heap+dump+programmatically+java).

Comment: Thank you for answer but it doesn't help. I want to capture heap dump for another process. I worked on the code you've sent before asking this question but could't find a way to to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Dynamic Attach API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html).

You'll still need to specify a file name where to save the dump.

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
import sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class HeapDump {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String pid = args[0];
        HotSpotVirtualMachine vm = (HotSpotVirtualMachine) VirtualMachine.attach(pid);

        try (InputStream in = vm.dumpHeap("/tmp/heapdump.hprof")) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[200];
            for (int bytes; (bytes = in.read(buf)) > 0; ) {
                System.out.write(buf, 0, bytes);
            }
        } finally {
            vm.detach();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it mandatory to read the `InputStream` or can the application read the specified file instead? And is printing a heap dump to the console really a good idea?

Comment: @Holger It's not the heap dump in the stream, but the message from the VM with the status of the operation: either an error message or a string like "Heap dump file created".

Comment: I see. I was confused, as the JMX variant doesn’t return anything. Then, Java 9‘s `in.transferTo(System.out);` would simplify that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a reference to a `sun. …` class, here’s the JMX API variant:

```
private static void dumpHeap(String pid, String targetFile) throws Exception {
    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
    String connectorAddress = vm.startLocalManagementAgent();
    JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddress));
    MBeanServerConnection sc = c.getMBeanServerConnection();
    sc.invoke(ObjectName.getInstance("com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic"),
        "dumpHeap",
        new Object[] { targetFile, true }, new String[]{ "java.lang.String", "boolean" });
}
```

The boolean argument corresponds to the “live” parameter, see also [`HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.dumpHeap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html#dumpHeap(java.lang.String,boolean))